# Google Apps Script: Replace all text in slide table with values and formatting from sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, replaceall, google-slides

Here is the description of my problem.

I have a range of placeholder text and its associated values in a spreadsheet. The placeholder text also exists in a slide presentation which gets replaced using the **replacealltext** function. However, the colors in the spreadsheet for the values do not change. Please see the examples below.

Google Apps Script:

```
  // Google Sheets
  var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = masterSheet.getSheetByName('Monthly Report'); //gets the data from the active pubfile
  var range = sheet.getRange('S1:T110');
  var data = range.getValues();
  var titleName = sheet.getRange('AA14:AA14').getValues().toString();
  data.shift(); //removes the headers in the sheets

  // Creating the new slide
  var spreadsheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); //Ensure Code is applied to active Pubfile
  var spreadsheetFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetID);
  var parentFolder = spreadsheetFolder.getParents();
  var folderID = parentFolder.next().getId();
  var reportTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('SLIDE ID'); // Gets the report Template
  var copiedTemplate = reportTemplate.makeCopy(titleName, DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)); //Makes a copy of the orginal and saves it in the specified folder
  var newPresoID = copiedTemplate.getId();
  var skeleton = SlidesApp.openById(newPresoID); //opens the new template presentation 
  var slides = skeleton.getSlides(); //calls the new slides 
  return newSlide1();

 function newSlide1() {
    var slide1new = slides[0]; // defining the location of the new slide 1
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      var templateVariable = row[0]; // First column contains variable names
      var templateValue = row[1]; // Second column contains values
      slide1new.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue); //replaces all the text that matches the placeholders
      slide1new.
    });
```

As you can see, this code just replaces the value but does not bring in the source formatting.

Here are snapshots of the original spreadsheet data and the slides:

[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Das2I.png)

[Destination Slide with Placeholders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSchV.png)

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpitq.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmjJ0.png)

Please suggest a way to fix this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of applying the colors of a spreadsheet cell to the table cells of a slide.

My spreadsheet looks like this.

[image]

My slide looks like this.

[image]

Code.gs

```
function myFunction() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,2);
    let values = range.getDisplayValues();
    let colors = range.getFontColors();

    let present = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    let slide = present.getSlides()[0];
    let table = slide.getTables()[0];
    for( let i=0; i<table.getNumRows(); i++ ) {
      let row = table.getRow(i);
      for( let j=1; j<row.getNumCells(); j++ ) {
        let text = row.getCell(j).getText();
        values.some( (value,k) => {
            let l = text.replaceAllText(value[0],value[1]);
            if( l > 0 ) {
              text.getTextStyle().setForegroundColor(colors[k][1]);
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

And the final results look like this.

[image]

Reference

- [TableCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell)
- [Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)

Comment: Hey @TheWizED, Thank you for your solution. I appreciate it. However, I do not want to insert/create a new table. The destination slides already have a template attached to them, and I just want to replace the values and the text color. Rest everything should remain as it is in the destination Slides, which is why I use the replace all text function. Is there a way to achieve that instead? Thank you again!

Comment: What I’ve shown is how to get formatting from the spreadsheet.  Just as you getValues(), and apply to your template, you can cell by cell apply the formatting.

Comment: Just a side note.  The first cell is merged and will throw an error if you include it in the j loop.  I skip it but this shows you how to do it.