# Google Sheets to Slides w/Apps Script - How do you keep cell text color?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, textcolor, google-slides

trying to move data from sheets to auto fill a template in Google Slides. I've gotten it to work, however, I want it to keep the colors of the font of the shapes. The shapes are just the font with color.  Any thoughts on what I need to add? (First timer here :)

[Sheet Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym3aN.png)

[Slide Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvROU.png)

[Final Output Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q9PN.png)

My code is below:

```
function createOneSlidePerRow() {
let masterDeckID = "deck ID";
let masterSheetID= "sheet ID"
let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
let slides = deck.getSlides();
let masterSlide = slides[1];

let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheetID).getDataRange();
let sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();
let header = sheetContents.shift();
let updatedContents = [];
sheetContents.reverse();
sheetContents.forEach(function (row) {
let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();

slide.replaceAllText("{{full_name}}", row[0]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{symbol_1}}", row[1]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{symbol_2}}", row[2]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{symbol_3}}", row[3]);
}
```

I found this but I have no idea how to adapt: [Google Apps Script: Replace all text in slide table with values and formatting from sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950724/google-apps-script-replace-all-text-in-slide-table-with-values-and-formatting-f)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question and showing script, I cannot understand your expected result. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situation you expect using your sample input situation? By the way, the cell of "Xyz" in your image is cell "A1"? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `however, I want it to keep the colors of the font of the shapes` Much would depend on how they were created. Would you please explain how each "shape" was created: perhaps inserted with the "drawing" tool, or perhaps they are "images", or perhaps some other method?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I've updated visuals to include output desired, better view of the sheet (images are symbol 1, 2, 3) and the slide template. The symbols are just symbol characters as text with color changed using the text color tool.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. When this script is run using your showing sample Spreadsheet and Slide, I think that your expected result is obtained. But, if this sample script was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and Slide? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

From your updated question, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set `masterDeckID` and `masterSheetID`.

```js
function createOneSlidePerRow() {
  let masterDeckID = "deck ID";
  let masterSheetID = "sheet ID"
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();
  let masterSlide = slides[1];
  let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheetID).getDataRange();

  // I modified the below script.
  const [header, ...values] = dataRange.getValues();
  const [, ...colors] = dataRange.getFontColorObjects();
  values.forEach((row, i) => {
    let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();
    slide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
      header.forEach((h, j) => {
        const text = s.getText();
        if (text.replaceAllText(h, row[j]) != 0) {
          const c = colors[i][j].asRgbColor().asHexString();
          text.getTextStyle().setForegroundColor(c.length > 7 ? "#000000" : c);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

- When this script is run using your showing sample Spreadsheet and Slide, I think that your expected result is obtained.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [getFontColorObjects()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFontColorObjects())
- [getTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#gettextstyle)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> This is so close! It brings in the color, but it makes all symbols the same color as Symbol 3 instead of letting them have their own unique color.

Will this script bring your expected result?

```js
function createOneSlidePerRow() {
  let masterDeckID = "deck ID";
  let masterSheetID = "sheet ID"
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();
  let masterSlide = slides[1];
  let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheetID).getDataRange();

  // I modified the below script.
  const [header, ...values] = dataRange.getValues();
  const headerColors = dataRange.getFontColorObjects()[0];
  values.forEach((row, i) => {
    let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();
    slide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
      header.forEach((h, j) => {
        const text = s.getText();
        if (text.replaceAllText(h, row[j]) != 0) {
          const c = headerColors[j].asRgbColor().asHexString();
          text.getTextStyle().setForegroundColor(c.length > 7 ? "#000000" : c);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This is so close! It brings in the color, but it makes all symbols the same color as Symbol 3 instead of letting them have their own unique color.

Comment: @Silverett Thank you for replying. About `This is so close! It brings in the color, but it makes all symbols the same color as Symbol 3 instead of letting them have their own unique color.`, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: So after playing with the spreadsheet to diagnose, it is taking the header color in column D and applying to each shape. Sample slide deck: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1vpIOnCp1tlzJ6LC-I8Ad1BLQxHtoIlYakk0q7t5C5Sc/edit#slide=id.g282227f4fd8_0_126 AND Sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0UTc2OKvkidzF3lMacA8NXSUshmuKmMAHFT70uydBs/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Silverett Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `So after playing with the spreadsheet to diagnose, it is taking the header color in column D and applying to each shape. Sample slide deck: docs.google.com/presentation/d/… AND Sample spreadsheet: docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…`, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the details of your reply? By the way, I cannot open your Slides and Spreadsheet. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Silverett In order to correctly understand your actual expected result, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? When I saw your sample images and proposed 2 scripts, it seemed that those were not your expected results. I think that the reason for this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?